# How to add 'Referrer-Policy' and 'Feature-Policy' headers to Tomcat for Jira 8

Tags: tomcat

When testing our site on https://securityheaders.com, it shows we are missing two headers:

1. Referrer-Policy
2. Feature-Policy

Our site is Jira 8.3.1 and it natively runs Tomcat. How do I configure Tomcat for these two headers?

I was able to set the Strict-Transport-Security header in the Tomcat web.xml file. I suspect I may be able to add these headers here too, just not sure what to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Just create Filter like below file ReferrerPolicyFilter.java and add ReferrerPolicyFilter filter in web.xml around other filters.

```
package my.package;

public class ReferrerPolicyFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) { }

@Override
public void destroy() { }

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = ((HttpServletResponse) response);
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

In web.xml add your filter with full package name.

```
  ...
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>ReferrerPolicyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.ReferrerPolicyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ReferrerPolicyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to do this in the meantime and posted some code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517443/where-does-my-servlet-filter-jar-go-for-tomcat-8-jira/57527314#57527314).